# efficient algorithms with array of increasing integers

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search, bisection

I've been self teaching myself data structures in python and don't know if I'm overthinking (or underthinking!) the following question:

- My goal is come up with an efficient algorithm
- With the algorithm, my goal is to determine whether an integer i exists such that A[i] = i in an array of increasing integers
- I then want to find the the running time in big-O notation as a function of n the length of A?

so wouldn't this just be a slightly modified version of O(log n) with a function equivalent to: f(i) = A[i] - i.  Am I reading this problem wrong?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: write some code for a start:) Your reasoning about complexity seems to be right.

Comment: Belongs to programmers SE, not here.

Comment: This boils down to finding zeroes in a function where f(x) = A[x] - x. Using bisection is just one possible way, another one is using a linear approximation between the two edges to find the probable position of the zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note 1: because you say the integers are increasing, you have ruled out that there are duplicates in the array (otherwise you would say monotonically increasing).  So a quick check that would rule out whether there is no solution is if the first element is larger than 1.   In other words, for there to be any chance of a solution, first element has to be <= 1.

Note 2: similar to Note 1, if last element is < length of array, then there is no solution.

In general, I think the best you can do is binary search.  You trap it between low and high indices, and then check the middle index between low and high.  If array[middle] equals middle, return yes.  If it is less than middle, then set left to middle+1.  Otherwise, set right to middle - 1.  If left becomes > right, return no.

Running time is O( log n ).

Edit: algorithm does NOT work if you allow monotonically increasing.  Exercise: explain why.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

- You're correct. Finding an element `i` in your `A` sized array is `O(Log A)` indeed.
- However, you can do much better: `O(Log A) -> O(1)` if you trade memory complexity for time complexity, which is what "optimizers" tend to do.

What I mean is: If you **insert** new Array elements into an "efficient" hash table you can achieve the `find` function in constant time `O(1)`

This is depends a lot on the elements you're inserting:

- Are they unique? Think of *collisions*
- How often do you `insert`?

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem :-)

You can use bisection to locate the place where `a[i] == i`:

```
       0  1  2  3  4  5  6
a = [-10 -5  2  5 12 20 100]

When i = 3,   i < a[i],  so bisect down
When i = 1    i > a[i],  so bisect up
When i = 2    i == a[i], you found the match
```

The running time is **O(log n)**.